# In PostGIS ST_MinimumBoundingRadius what unit of measure is the radius of the returned number?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, radius

I have a function that I wrote in PLPGSQL to get the Minimum Bounding Radius added below (it uses the ST_MinimumBoundingRadius() function. It seems to be working because I get a number returned. However; I am not sure what that number represents. Is it miles, meters, kilometers, or some variation on longitude/latitude degrees?

The second function is a test function that builds an input polygon and then invokes my function.

After the 2 functions are the definitions for the tfr_point_type data type and tfr_polygon table that the functions use.

Thanks in advance for any help that is available.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tfr_get_minimum_bounding_radius(
    the_polygon tfr_polygon)
    RETURNS SETOF double precision 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE LEAKPROOF STRICT PARALLEL SAFE 
    ROWS 1

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    the_radius double PRECISION;
    points_array geometry[];        -- collects geometry of the points in the LOOP and then used to calculate the radius
    point tfr_point_type;           -- used in the LOOP

BEGIN

FOREACH point IN ARRAY the_polygon.points LOOP

    points_array := array_append(
        points_array,
        ST_MakePoint(
                    point.longitudedec,
                    point.latitudedec,
                    point.altitude
                    )
    );

END LOOP;

SELECT radius
INTO the_radius
FROM ST_MinimumBoundingRadius(
        ST_MakePolygon(
                ST_MakeLine(
                        points_array
                    )
            )
    );

RETURN NEXT the_radius;

END;
$BODY$;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tfr_test_polygon(
    )
    RETURNS SETOF  double precision
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE LEAKPROOF STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
--    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
point1 public.tfr_point_type;
point2 public.tfr_point_type;
point3 public.tfr_point_type;
point4 public.tfr_point_type;
point5 public.tfr_point_type;

londms tfr_longitude_direction;
latdms tfr_latitude_direction;

a_polygon public.tfr_polygon;
points public.tfr_point_type[];

center geometry;
circle_radius double PRECISION;


--north public.tfr_latitude_direction := 'North'::tfr_latitude_direction;
--south public.tfr_latitude_direction := 'South'::tfr_latitude_direction;
--east public.tfr_longitude_direction := 'East'::tfr_longitude_direction;
--west public.tfr_longitude_direction := 'West'::tfr_longitude_direction;

BEGIN


RAISE log '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++';

point1.longitudedec = -84.351;
point1.latitudedec = 42.4643;
point1.altitude = 11000;
point1.wkt = st_AsHexEwkb(st_makepoint(point1.longitudedec, point1.latitudedec, point1.altitude));

point2.longitudedec = -104.351;
point2.latitudedec = 43.4643;
point2.altitude = 12000;
point2.wkt = st_AsHexEwkb(st_makepoint(point2.longitudedec, point2.latitudedec, point2.altitude));

point3.longitudedec = -74.351;
point3.latitudedec = 43.4643;
point3.altitude = 13000;
point3.wkt = st_AsHexEwkb(st_makepoint(point3.longitudedec, point3.latitudedec, point3.altitude));

point4.longitudedec = -74.351;
point4.latitudedec = 42.4643;
point4.altitude = 14000;
point4.wkt = st_AsHexEwkb(st_makepoint(point4.longitudedec, point4.latitudedec, point4.altitude));

point5.longitudedec = -84.351;
point5.latitudedec = 42.4643;
point5.altitude = 15000;
point5.wkt = st_AsHexEwkb(st_makepoint(point5.longitudedec, point5.latitudedec, point5.altitude));

RAISE log 'I created point1: %', point1;
RAISE log 'I created point2: %', point2;
RAISE log 'I created point3: %', point3;
RAISE log 'I created point4: %', point4;
RAISE log 'I created point5: %', point5;

points := array_append(points, point1);
points := array_append(points, point2);
points := array_append(points, point3);
points := array_append(points, point4);
points := array_append(points, point5);
    
a_polygon.id := 1;
a_polygon.points := points;

RAISE log 'I created a_polygon: %', a_polygon;

RAISE log '========================================';

SELECT *
INTO circle_radius
FROM public.tfr_get_minimum_bounding_radius(a_polygon);

RAISE log 'The raidus is: %', circle_radius;

--
RETURN QUERY
SELECT public.tfr_get_minimum_bounding_radius(a_polygon) AS radius;




END;
$BODY$;
```

```
CREATE TYPE public.tfr_point_type AS
(
    wkt character varying,
    longitudedec double precision,
    latitudedec double precision,
    altitude double precision,
);

ALTER TYPE public.tfr_point_type
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Polygon Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tfr_polygon
(
     id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('shape_base_id_seq'::regclass),
     points tfr_point_type[]
)
   
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Answer (score 1):

as with most PostGIS functions, the returned unit is the same as the input CRS, so in your example it is likely in degrees.